# How can I animate a histogram of occurrences using Plotly Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, plotly

I want to animate a histogram over a `DataFrame` index, so that as the index increases, the bins fill up. My `DataFrame` is structured like this:

| Index | Ingredient |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Onions |
| 2 | Onions |
| 3 | Garlic |
| 4 | Onions |
| 5 | Tomato |
| 6 | Tomato |
| 7 | Onions |

At the beginning of the animation, all bins should be initialized at 0, and fill up as the index increases. I have tried the following using `plotly.express.histogram`.

```
idx = df.index
fig = px.histogram(df, x="Ingredient",
    animation_frame=idx, animation_group=idx, cumulative=True,
)
```

The result I get is an animated histogram with **only one bin** that switches between the ingredient names as it goes through the `DataFrame`, with the height of the bin staying constant at 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- approach is to prepare a dataframe that is ready for animation
- then it's simple to create an animated **bar** to create figure you have defined

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import io

df = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
        """Index,Ingredient
1,Onions
2,Onions
3,Garlic
4,Onions
5,Tomato
6,Tomato
7,Onions"""
    )
)


ings = df["Ingredient"].value_counts()
df2 = pd.concat(
    [
        pd.DataFrame({"Ingredient": ings.index})
        .merge(
            df.loc[df["Index"].le(i)].groupby("Ingredient", as_index=False).size(),
            on="Ingredient",
            how="left",
        )
        .assign(Index=i)
        .fillna(0)
        for i in range(df["Index"].min(), df["Index"].max() + 1)
    ]
)

px.bar(df2, x="Ingredient", y="size", animation_frame="Index").update_layout(
    yaxis={"range": [0, ings.max()]}
)
```

[image]